# GSuite: "There should not be a mail exchanger set up on naked domain name"

Tags: domain-name-system, email, g-suite, a-record

I checked my domain name with [GSuite's MX tool](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/checkmx/) to find out why our email gets to Spam folders, and have resolved the main issues (SPF and DKIM entries were missing in our DNS settings). The last problem is this:

> "There should not be a mail exchanger set up on naked domain name"

[image]

Previously there was an A entry pointing to mail server of our hosting in DNS settings and I have removed it (since we use Google's mail servers anyways).

A few hours have passed, so maybe I just need to wait a bit longer, or should I do something else besides this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This warning is not about your DNS records, it's about your server: The server to which the DNS address records for `example.com` refers. They are saying that that server is running a mail server that answered port 25. There should be no mail server receiving mail on that server.

Comment: But since this is a shared hosting plan, I don't think our hosting provider will turn off the mail server, since some other users surely uses it. I guess this situation happens a lot because most of the people I know also use shared hosting plans and then use Gmail (GSuite) to acces their mail. Should I just ignore the error?

Comment: If your website is on shared hosting, then there's nothing you can do about it except to move elsewhere. You'll have to ignore the error and hope you never lose mail.

Answer (score 0):

> Previously there was an A entry pointing to mail server of our hosting
>   in DNS settings and I have removed it (since we use Google's mail
>   servers anyways).

The fact that you use G Suite for your email doesn't negate the need for MX records. The G Suite documentation lists the MX records you should create in your DNS zone.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/174125?hl=en

Comment: I added MX records to DNS zone.